# UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor is transparent

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, ios, uicolor

I have a grouped style `UITableView` on my navigation stack, and when I click on a cell, I push a `UIDatePicker` onto the stack.  The problem is that I want this custom view to have the same background color as my table view.

I tried setting the background color of my custom view like:

`datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];`

But this comes out transparent.  I also tried modifying the underlying `CGColor` object to have an alpha of 1.0, which caused the background color to be black.

The following *does* work as expected:

`datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];`

But, of course, this color doesn't quite match the grouped table background color.

Am I going about this all wrong?  I found a similar post about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157431/uiview-on-ipad-with-grouptableviewbackgroundcolor), but no helpful response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean you "push a UIDatePicker onto the stack"? Why dont you try animating the UIDatePicker into view?

when the view loads, create the picker and set the frame off screen, such as

```
    [picker setFrame:CGRectMake(0,960,320,216)];
```

then instead of "pushing" the picker, animate it into view like:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [picker setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,216)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

And when you want to dismiss the picker, just hide it like:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [picker setFrame:CGRectMake(0,960,320,216)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

If you need to, you can also add a toolbar with a "done" button to dismiss the picker, works great for me.

If the contents of the picker are going to be displayed on the table, then you can set the frame of the table in that animation sequence. in the first one, make the table half the size (like 150 for my example would work perfect), then in the hide sequence, make the table the original size (415 for this example). And when you hide the picker, call `[tableView reloadData];` to refresh the table.

Comment: Thanks - I guess I was going about it completely wrong.  This is much better.

Comment: The only problem that I'm having with this solution, is that I can't get the table view to resize.  Calling `setFrame` on the `tableView` seems to have no effect.

Comment: The UITableView HAS to be in a UIView. If your controller is a UITableViewController, then you will not be able to resize it.